# Remove and append middle column from a 3D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a 3D numpy array A, say given below:

```
A = np.array( [[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]] , [[7,8,9] , [10,11,12], [13,14,15]] ] , ndmin = 3 )
```

The only thing given about A is that it is a 3D arrays which is an array of arbitrary number of 2D arrays, where each 2D array is an array of arbitrary number of 1D arrays, and each 1D array has exactly 3 elements.

I want to remove the middle element from each 1D array from this 3D array, basically get the new array A1, and the removed column as X given below:

```
A1 = np.array( [[[1,3], [4,6]] , [[7,9] , [10,12], [13,15]] ] , ndmin = 3 )
X  = np.array( [ [[2],[5]], [[8],[11],[14]] ], ndmin = 3 )
```

I want to write a function that given A it outputs (A1, X) and another function which given (A1, X) outputs A. I believe it should be possible to write the first function via array slicing, but I am not able to do so. Also how do I write the second function.

Comment: do you intend to create a ragged array `A` or is it a typo?

Comment: @ZLi Yes, It's ragged intentionally. Only structure on A is that each 1D array has 3 elements, rest there can be as many 1D or 2D arrays.

Comment: just curious, why do you restrict this to numpy? As numpy does not have good support for ragged arrays

Comment: Because I treat A1 as a list of * \times 3 matrices, and I need to use matrix multiplication (so np.dot on each element of A1 with some other matrix). Essentially I need to do: (A) -> (A1,X) -> (T*A1, X) -> (B)

Comment: The data you provided would be an array of lists right? Of size (1, 1, 2) and each element is a list, not `np.array`

Comment: @ZLi I'm not sure what you mean. A is defined as a 3D numpy array. I'm guessing this implies that A[0] = C is a 2D numpy array and C[0] would be a 1D numpy array.

Comment: You can't do this with numpy since ragged arrays to numpy are as useable as NaN or strings. Would you be fine with list-comprehension? It's usually impressively fast.

Comment: @richardec I think there are predefined functions to go from numpy arrays to python lists and vice versa, so this should be fine.

Comment: @Kaind ragged arrays are of object type in numpy. Each element would be a list instead of numpy array. But that could be different in older versions. Could you try to print out A and share the output?

Comment: @Kaind unless your data can be reshaped, it's not possible (to my knowledge) to do this just using numpy, since the lists aren't rectangular, which is all numpy will work with. You've got a list containng two 3-item lists and another list containg three 3-item lists...

Comment: Why is `A` ragged in the first place? This data structure doesn't seem to make a whole lot of sense. You lose all the benefits of numpy by defining `A` that way.

Comment: @richardec I see so maybe I should change my representation as a python list of 2D numpy arrays instead of a 3D numpy array? @Z Li I'll try to that in the evening, I'll have to switch machines.

Comment: that is what I meant. It is better to use a list of numpy arrays

Comment: @Kaind try this: `[[[[[e for i, e in enumerate(d) if i != 1] for d in c] for c in b] for b in a] for a in A]` - are you okay with something like that monster? :D If so I'll write an answer.

Comment: @ddejohn The data structure isn't a matrix, it's actually represents a DNF.

Comment: What is a DNF and why can't it be represented using rectangular arrays? Is the data of `A` *intrinsically* ragged? If so then this is probably the wrong data structure to be using, period.

Comment: @richardec Maybe I'll just switch my notation to a list of 2D numpy arrays, rather than a 3D array.

Comment: @ddejohn DNF = disjunctive normal formula. Each 1D array is a predicate (fixed size), but the number of conjuncts and disjuncts could vary.

Comment: I see, so these ragged groupings correspond to various DNF boolean phrases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For you ragged array, it is better to store in a list of np.arrays with shape n by 3:

```
A = [np.array([[1,2,3],
               [4,5,6]]) ,
     np.array([[7,8,9],
               [10,11,12],
               [13,14,15]])]
```

Now you could:

```
def remove_middle(arr):
    x = [a[:, 1] for a in arr]
    arr_new = [np.delete(a, 1, axis = 1) for a in arr]
    return arr_new, x

def insert_middle(arr, x):
    return [np.concatenate([a[:, :1], xx.reshape(-1, 1), a[:, 1:]], axis = 1) for a, xx in zip(arr, x)]
```

```
remove_middle(A)
```

```
([array([[1, 3],
         [4, 6]]),
  array([[ 7,  9],
         [10, 12],
         [13, 15]])],
 [array([2, 5]), array([ 8, 11, 14])])
```

```
insert_middle(*remove_middle(A))
```

```
# gets back the original A
[array([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]]),
 array([[ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15]])]
```

Comment: Why `np.delete`? Why not `arr[:, (0, 2)]`? Is `np.delete` faster?

Comment: not necessarily. It provides a copy instead of a view, which could be useful if you plan to keep the original data, and it is flexible in case the shape changes

Comment: Ah, fwiw advanced indexing produces a copy too.

Answer (score 1):

Without the ndmin=3 argument I can solve your answer using two nested list comprehensions in which the first indexes the middle argument and the second one deletes the middle argument of the inner arrays.

```
import numpy
A = np.array([[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]] , [[7,8,9] , [10,11,12], [13,14,15]]])
middle = [[array1d[1] for array1d in array2d] for array2d in A]
without_middle = [[np.delete(array1d, 1) for array1d in array2d] for array2d in A]
```

Comment: I would suggest to reduce the number of nested for loops as it grows at `O(nm)` when data is large (not sure what data op is using)

Answer (score 1):

With your strange data, this absurd-looking quintuple-nested list-comprehension is the best I could come up with :P

```
A1 = [[[[[e for i, e in enumerate(d) if i != 1] for d in c] for c in b] for b in a] for a in A]
X = [[[[[e for i, e in enumerate(d) if i == 1] for d in c] for c in b] for b in a] for a in A]
```

Output:

```
>>> A1
[[[[[1, 3], [4, 6]], [[7, 9], [10, 12], [13, 15]]]]]

>>> X
[[[[[2], [5]], [[8], [11], [14]]]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. Note that lists are returned as raw python list which you can use as you want.

I changed your definition of A to a more suitable object.

```
import numpy as np


def f(A):
    A1 = A.tolist()
    X  = []
    for i in range(len(A1)):
        temp = []
        for j in range(len(A1[i])):
            temp.append([A1[i][j].pop(1)])
        X.append(temp)

    return (A1, X)

def g(A1, X):
    A = A1
    for i in range(len(A1)):
        for j in range(len(A1[i])):
            A[i][j].insert(1, X[i][j][0])

    return A


def main():
    #A = np.array( [ [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ] , [ [7,8,9] , [10,11,12], [13,14,15] ] ] , ndmin = 3 )
    A = np.asarray([ [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ] , [ [7,8,9] , [10,11,12], [13,14,15] ] ])

    B, X = f(A)

    print(g(B,X))

    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Finally please note that this is one solution among many possible alternatives.